# Change download folder for deluge-daemon

Tags: server, mount, permissions, deluge

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and I setted up a

/var/systemd/system/deluge-daemon.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Deluge Bittorrent Client Daemon
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=deluge
Group=deluge
UMask=007

ExecStart=/usr/bin/deluged -d

Restart=on-failure

# Configures the time to wait before service is stopped forcefully.
TimeoutStopSec=300

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/var/systemd/system/deluge-web.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Deluge Bittorrent Client Web Interface
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple

User=deluge
Group=deluge
UMask=027

ExecStart=/usr/bin/deluge-web

Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And the service was working.

After that I setted up to mount another hard disk on the boot, here is my fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=376f4302-e8f7-4e86-ac8d-f814ed810e43 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=30916bc6-913e-44e4-979c-e158f11d9abf /media/agusgambina/30916bc6-913e-44e4-979c-e158f11d9abf ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=7d282884-f8ae-4002-b59e-a516fea1763d none            swap    sw              0       0
```

my "second" disk is the one that mounts in this point `/media/agusgambina/30916bc6-913e-44e4-979c-e158f11d9abf`

then I changed the folder permissions. The owner of the folder is the user deluge and it belongs to the group deluge

```
$ chown deluge:deluge -R /media/agusgambina/30916bc6-913e-44e4-979c-e158f11d9abf/deluge
```

After that, in the application I changed the download directory to the new folder. But every time I try to start a new download I get an Error of permission denied

```
Permission denied: /media/agusgambina/30916bc6-913e-44e4-979c-e158f11d9abf/deluge/temp/ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
```

---

Update 1:

here are the folder permissions

```
drwxrwxr-x 53 deluge      deluge      4096 sep 28 00:46 incoming/
drwxrwxr-x  2 deluge      deluge      4096 ene  1  2016 logs/
drwxrwxr-x  2 deluge      deluge      4096 jul  7 20:01 temp/
drwxrwxr-x  2 deluge      deluge      4096 dic 31  2015 torrents/
```

---

Update 2:

permissions for /media/agusgambina

```
drwx-----x  8 agusgambina agusgambina 4096 ene  3  2016 30916bc6-913e-44e4-979c-e158f11d9abf/
```

Answer (score 0):

You changed ownership, but does the owner have write access to  that directory ?

Do

```
ls -laF /media/agusgambina/30916bc6-913e-44e4-979c-e158f11d9abf/deluge/
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I updated the question. I have the permissions to write on that directory with the user deluge.

Comment: Then check permissions on /media/agusgambina, I guess it is missing 'x' for other users.

Comment: I think we are close to get where I made the mistake. I updated the question the 'x' is for other users. Thank you for your comments @user596137